# Is there a limit for ARAnchors in a worldmap?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

Is there a limit or best practice for the max number of ARAnchors added manually to a ARWorldTrackingconfiguration. I'm experiencing some weird framework errors and this might be due to the fact that I have 15+ ARAnchors placed + ARPlaneAnchors that are added automatically. I haven't found documentation on this matter.

---

[] Assert: in line 659
Assert: in line 659
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib:/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think its 10, not quite sure though.

The view limit is 10 so it'd make sense if it was the same.